# custom payment method place order disabled

Tags: magento2.3, orders, payment-methods

I've created a new custom payment method It's added to the methods but when I choose it in checkout the Place Order button is disabled and there is no text in the button. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Matyasovszki Máté,

Can you please share some of your code its looking like you are missing the Billing address block in your payment method.

Can you please check if you can look a billing address block when its select custom payment method which you developed.

Check with guest and also login case and if its missing then put that code in your checkout knockout xml file you can see its enable your button of the Place order.

Thanks